# C# not retrieving blob from Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a series of blobs which I would like to process. My program is getting a 404 error, throwing an exception like this:

```
ErrorCode:BlobNotFound
ErrorMessage:The specified blob does not exist.
```

The access policy on the container is set properly, and when I paste the logged URI into my browser (for instance, this: `https://atpblob.blob.core.windows.net/darkskydata/plot1251time2010-01-02t00:00:01z.json`), it downloads fine.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Console.WriteLine(daily.BlobUri);
 CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(daily.BlobUri);
 string text;
 using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
  blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);
  text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
 }
 Console.WriteLine(text);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is with the following line of code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(daily.BlobUri);
```

If you look at [`GetBlockBlobReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) documentation, the parameter expected is actually blob's name and not the URL.

Please try changing it to blob's name. For testing purpose, please try the following code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("plot1251time2010-01-02t00:00:01z.json");
```

You should not get an error.